# Renaming a Group Chat in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new to Discord.py. I wanted to know if it was possible to rename a group chat on Discord using Python. I am aware that this is selfbot and that it breaks their ToS. But if it is possible can someone lead me in the right direction please. I have this so far: `await discord.GroupChannel.edit(channel, name = "test")` however I get a invalid syntax.

WHOLE CODE:

```
import discord
from discord import Member
import json
import pyfiglet
import asyncio
import time
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import sty
from sty import fg, bg, ef, rs
import speedtest

bot = commands.Bot(description="SelfBot v2_1_0.2!", 
command_prefix="!", self_bot=True)
bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
await discord.GroupChannel.edit(channel, name = "test")

token = "token goes here" 
bot.run(token, bot=False)
```

Comment: Since you mentioned invalid syntax, can you add the error traceback to your question?

Comment: sure! I updated it with my whole code

Comment: Please note that self bots are [**against discord TOS**](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-) and will get your account **banned and terminated**. It would be better if you used a normal bot, whether this is for 'testing purposes' or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a few misconceptions about `async`/`await`, so I highlighted the most critical issues below:

1. The `@bot.event` decorator must decorate a function (you are attempting to decorate a function call, thus the `SyntaxError`). Since the `discord.GroupChannel.edit()` call would have to be inside a coroutine function (all `await` statements must be inside a coroutine), the function should be defined using `async def`.
2. `channel` must be defined and it should be a [`discord.GroupChannel` object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.GroupChannel).

*For (2), you could select a specific group channel which the bot is in by using the [`Bot.private_channels` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.htmlt#discord.ext.commands.Bot.private_channels). This returns a list of all the private channels the bot is in, each being a [`discord.abc.PrivateChannel` object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.PrivateChannel)*(`discord.GroupChannel` objects implement the `discord.abc.PrivateChannel` type).